# Is it possible to use a single Spring DataSource with multiple TransactionManagers?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using `Spring`. I have a bunch of services which are being used by a single desktop application. Since this is not a distributed system, all the services are part of the application itself, they are not running remotely (I am aware this might not be ideal).

Instead of having a different data source for each service, I wanted to use the same data source for all the services in order to reduce the number of db connections. I have achieved this using the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. I inject the shared data source to all the beans that allow a data source.

The issue I'm running into is that although the application seems to load up correctly, all the beans are initialized correctly and data source is injected without a problem, when I try to do anything in the application I get the following exception:

```
"org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: 
Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! 
HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. 
It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access."
```

I also have to mention that I'm using both `HibernateTransactionManagers` and `DataSourceTransactionManagers`. `DataSourceTransactionManagers` are used when dealing with `JDBC`, `HibernateTransactionManagers` are used for services using Hibernate.

I tried using a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` to wrap my shared data source for use with the `DataSourceTransactionManagers` but this had no effect.

Does the above exception mean that I might have to use a single transaction manager?

Comment: How about following the suggestion and only use a HibernateTransactionManager for both scenarios?

Comment: I might not be understanding the error message correctly. Do they mean a single instance of HibernateTransactionManager or single type of the transaction manager in a single application?

Comment: Actually I think they mean both.

Comment: What you suggested worked. It was a bit tricky. I used the BeanFactoryPostProcessor to harvest all the Hibernate mappings from all the session factories. I combined them into a single list and set them on the new session factory. So now I have a single transaction manager which uses the new session factory which in turn uses the shared connection pool. All seems to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, sounds tricky, too. ;)

Comment: The exception is a bit misleading, and agreed by Spring - https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/spring-and-pre-bound-jdbc-connection-found/. Just my two cents.